# ng-model scope not available while using with ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I am just trying to implement a simple drop down and here is my code

```
<select ng-change="selectTestSuite();" ng-model="testCase" ng-options="testSuite.TEST_NAME for testSuite in publicTestCase"></select>
```

In the controller when I am trying to print value of testCase in console it is giving undefined. But When I try to print id of testCase using

```
{{testCase.TEST_ID}}
```

It is giving me id. I have also checked by using $watch

```
$scope.$watch('testCase',function() {
   console.log($scope.testCase);
});
```

Unable to figure out where I am making mistake.Appreciate any help.

Comment: how did you print?

Comment: your code is working fine .. check this - http://jsfiddle.net/b7tLpca7/

Comment: will you please share the contents of publicTestCase?

Answer (score 0):

I think no problem with ng-options.

Actually ng-options maps the "testSuite.TEST_NAME" as model to ng-model.

Ensure the "testSuite.TEST_NAME" is available in "publicTestCase" collection (Whether it is undefined).

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the testCase to testSuite.TEST_NAME.
Your ng-options should look like this:

```
<select ng-change="selectTestSuite()" ng-model="testCase" ng-options="testSuite as testSuite.TEST_NAME for testSuite in publicTestCase"></select>
```

The model gets bind to the value of testSuite from the records in the publicTestCase array and for each of the testSuite you want the testSuite.TEST_NAME to be shown as the options text.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxe41.png)

Note:- Please find the image link.image contains code
ng-repeat directive repeats a block of HTML code for each item in an array, it can be used to create options in a dropdown list, but the ng-options directive was made especially for filling a dropdown list with options, and has at least one important advantage:

Dropdowns made with ng-options allows the selected value to be an object, while dropdowns made from ng-repeat has to be a string.